# File shows up in ls but cannot rm or mv, seems to be held by some unknown process

Tags: rm, kill, lsof

I do a lot of work on an SGE cluster running CentOS 7, and have recently had issues with jobs dying randomly, but seemingly with some processes still running that prevent me from cleaning up to start over. When I try to delete the necessary files, I get a "no such file or directory" message, yet the file shows up in `ls`. Forum searches told me this could be because of non-printing characters in the name, but I can't create a file with the same name using `touch`, or remove it with `rm -i`, and nothing shows up with `ls -b` or `ls -Q`. E.g:

```
[ark19@blade04 testing]$ rm file_bad.csv 
rm: cannot remove ‘file_bad.csv’: No such file or directory
[ark19@blade04 testing]$ rm -f file_bad.csv 
[ark19@blade04 testing]$ ls file*
file1.csv  file2.csv  file_bad.csv
[ark19@blade04 testing]$ ls -l file*
-rwx——— 1 ark19 root  88552 Dec 26 18:31 file1.csv
-rwx——— 1 ark19 root  87149 Dec 26 18:32 file2.csv
-rwx——— 1 ark19 root 183588 Dec 27 19:45 file_bad.csv
[ark19@blade04 testing]$ ls -b file*
file1.csv  file2.csv  file_bad.csv
[ark19@blade04 testing]$ ls -Q file*
"file1.csv"  "file2.csv"  "file_bad.csv"
[ark19@blade04 testing]$ touch file_bad.csv 
touch: cannot touch ‘file_bad.csv’: No such file or directory
[ark19@blade04 testing]$ rm -i -- file_bad.csv 
rm: cannot remove ‘file_bad.csv’: No such file or directory
[ark19@blade04 testing]$ ls file*
file1.csv  file2.csv  file_bad.csv
```

As such I'm fairly certain the issue is that the bad file is being held by some process, and when I brought it up with the cluster admins the only solution they came up with was giving them the file name so that they could delete it. This has been happening too frequently for that to be a sustainable solution, so I wanted to ask here if there is anything else I can do to solve the problem myself, like to somehow force delete the file and close all processes that are getting in the way?

Most of the time I don't know which cluster node the suspected process is running on, and I don't know of a way to somehow check all of them to find and kill the appropriate process… If I run the `lsof` command from the node I'm logged into, it never turns up anything.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What happens if you type `touch file_` and then use TAB to complete the filename, does it work then? Or use `ls -lB file*`?

Comment: `touch file_` + TAB autocompletes file_bad.csv, then says: `touch: cannot touch ‘file_bad.csv’: No such file or directory`. `ls -lB file*` looks no different than `ls -l file*`.  For these reasons I'm increasingly convinced that it's not a non-printing character issue, but some kind of lock by some process, but I can't figure out how to find/kill/rm it.

Comment: If you run `dmesg`, do you see any errors related to the device on which these files are stored?

Comment: hmm, thanks for the suggestion @AndyDalton. I'm not too sure how to parse the `dmesg` output, but there are lots of "CIFS VFS" error messages in the more recent entries that seem like they could be relevant, including `CIFS VFS: Server <name> has not responded in 120 seconds.  Reconnecting…` and then several lines of `CIFS VFS: open dir failed`. I don't know too much about the filesystem on the cluster / server I'm using (or file systems in general really), so I'm not really sure where to go from here, but if this provides any clues as to what I should look at next I'd love to hear ideas!

Comment: Try running this in the director you're having trouble with: `df  .`  That should show you the filesystem and where it's mounted.  If the filesystem has an address, it could be that you're accessing files on a remote host, and that there's something wrong on the remote end.

Comment: The VFS can be out of sync with the file system driver?

Comment: It's indeed a remote host - I'm logged into an interactive node on a cluster, and the server with all of the data is mounted to it.  I can interact normally with all of the other files/folders on the server but presumably some process is holding onto this one file.  It's feeling more and more like I can't fix this without admin access to the cluster / server, but I'll still dare to hope...

Comment: What does `ls -l file*` show?

Comment: @Barmar I edited the post to include the output of `ls -l file*`; the permissions etc don't look any different for file_bad than the others :-/

Comment: I'll bet there are spaces at the end of the filename. `ls -B` doesn't show these, try `ls -b file_bad.*`. It will probably show something like `file_bad.csv\ `

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Barmar, though nothing shows up with `ls -b` or `ls -Q` (edited post to include it). I originally considered non-printing characters, but for these reasons and bc e.g `touch file_bad.csv` doesn't work either (reasoning that if there were non-printing characters then that should successfully create a new file bc the name is actually different), I don't think that's the case.  So far it seems the best clue is the CIFS VFS errors revealed by dmesg as in @Andy's suggestion but as I mentioned in my previous comment I'm not yet sure what to do with that information.